# Login to Google Maps' api

Tags: php

I'm trying to write the following code in order to fetch data from the api of Google Maps:

```
    $handle = curl_init();

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Chicago&destinations=New York&mode=driving&language=pl-PL&key=[api_key]";
// Set the url

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Set the result output to be a string.

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($handle);
```

But it shows me 'Error 400'!
How do I solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't include secret/private keys in your question. It can be seen/used(abused) by anyone on the internet. Please revoke/regenerate it (your GoogleMaps API Key in `key` param) ASAP.

Comment: what's the status of this question? If an answer given solved it, it should be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL-encode special characters like space.

In your case, instead of `New York` use `New%20York` and it works.

Do it dynamically like this:

```php
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".urlencode('Chigaco')."&destinations=".urlencode('New York')."&mode=driving&language=pl-PL&key=secret";
```

See http://php.net/urlencode

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're working with a JSON file, in which case it need to be treated differently.

For example:

```
<?php

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Chicago&destinations=New%20York&mode=driving&language=pl-PL&key=YOUR_API_KEY";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($result);
$address = $data->destination_addresses;

echo $address[0];
?>
```

Will return:

```
Nowy Jork, Stany Zjednoczone
```

**EDIT**

You can use simplexml_load_file too. It's more practical and easier.

For example:

```
<?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Chicago&destinations=New%20York&mode=driving&language=pl-PL&key=YOUR_KEY");

    echo "Origin Address: <b>" . $xml->origin_address . "</b><br />";
    echo "Destination Address: <b>" . $xml->destination_address . "</b><br />";
    echo "Duration: <b>" . $xml->row->element->duration->text . "</b><br />";
    echo "Distance: <b>" . $xml->row->element->distance->text . "</b><br />";

?>
```